# How to configure Custom LoginModule of JAAS with Jboss fuse

Tags: java, jboss, jaas, jbossfuse

Im try to configure my custom LoginModule of JAAS in jboss fuse blueprint but it always ends with the following excpetions

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.karaf.jaas.config.JaasRealm not found by log-query [335]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1853)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:958)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.loadClass(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.convertStringsToClasses(ServiceRecipe.java:432)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.getClassesForProxying(ServiceRecipe.java:422)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.createService(ServiceRecipe.java:302)
    ... 47 more
```

Below is my blueprint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:jaas="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0">

    <jaas:config name="JaasConfig" rank="2">
        <jaas:module className="pk.com.herman.jaas.JaasLoginModule"
            flags="required">
        </jaas:module>
    </jaas:config>
</blueprint>
```

Comment: Take a look https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/ch12s04.html

Comment: @FedericoSierra thanks alot for the reference, helped me alot and worked... i have a query what is meant by dynamic imports in java. n difference between static and dynamic. would you please help me in this too

Comment: You're welcome, about your problem with dynamics import please post a new question.